# API Blueprint: Semantic Issue "no value(s) specified"

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

In my blueprint I'm defining a data structure and try to use it like so

```
+ Attributes

    + error: (Error Details, required)
```

Data structure definition at the end of the document:

```
# Data Structures

## Error Details
+ code : 1234 (number, required) - see list of error codes
+ message: User not found (string, required) - a human-readable error message
```

The resulting sample response body looks just like expected but the validation on apiary.io shows semantic issues for each of the places where I use constructs like this, saying "No value(s) specified".

Am I doing something wrong or is it a problem with the apiary.io parser?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it by

1. omitting the colon
2. separating the object definition and type (see `owner` in this example):

   ### Company (object)

   - name: Company name (string)
   - owner (OwnerResponse) (object)

Answer (score 0):

Attribute section can be also defined as `+ Attributes <Type Definition>` ([specification](https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/specification.html#def-attributes-section)), so defining `+ Attributes (Error Details, required)` should fix the given semantic issue.

**Edit:**

You have to omit a colon between attribute's name and its type, when an example value is not defined:

```
+ Attributes

    + error (Error Details, required)
```

Missed that before, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately that would only work in this very specific instance. If the attribute type is, for example, an enum, it doesn't. I want to avoid repeating the enum definition in multiple places but specifying a sample value would duplicate that value in the list of allowed values on apiary.io, too.

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer to other current answers, but none the less this fixed it for me.

No good:

```
+ Attributes
    + `status`: OK
    + `data`:
        + 5 (Channeldata)
        + 7 (Channeldata)
```

Fix:

```
+ Attributes
    + `status`: OK
    + `data`
        + 5 (Channeldata)
        + 7 (Channeldata)
```

As others have noted, losing a colon in the right place can fix things.